# Looking for Django any() and all() on querysets

Tags: django, combinations, django-queryset

I have a form that has a group of 13 checkboxes that together make up my search criteria... except that I also added a pair of radio buttons for ALL or ANY.

I was hoping to get away with something elegant like:

```
priority_ids = request.GET.getlist("priority")  # checkboxes
collection   = request.GET.get("collection")    # radio buttons
priorities = []
for priority_id in priority_ids:
    priorities.append(Q(focus__priority=priority_id))
if   (collection == "any"): qset = any(priorities)
elif (collection == "all"): qset = all(priorities)
```

However, any() and all() return a boolean, not a queryset that I can use in a filter.  I want an "any" or "all" that does the equivalent of "Q(...) | Q(...) | Q(...)" or "Q(...) & Q(...) & Q(...)" for anywhere from 1 to 13 criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that Django needs to do about that. You just need to combine your `Q`-s with `&` and respectively `|`, in a simple loop or in a more compact way with `reduce`.

And regarding terminology it seems to me that you are calling `Q` a queryset, but it's not. It's a filter on a queryset. 
Something like the below should work:

```
priority_ids = request.GET.getlist("priority")
collection   = request.GET.get("collection")
priority_filters = []
for priority_id in priority_ids:
    priority_filters.append(Q(focus__priority=priority_id))

base_qs = SomeModel.objects.all()

if collection == "any":
   filtered_qset = base_qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, priority_filters))
elif collection == "all":
   filtered_qset = base_qs.filter(reduce(operator.and_, priority_filters))
```

Comment: Note that your `lambda`s can be replaced by `operator.or_` and `operator.and_`, respectively.

Comment: While we're at it, might as well do `priority_filters = [Q(focus__priority=p_id) for p_id in priority_ids]` :)

Comment: Also, the `any` case could probably be handled by using an `__in` lookup type (`SomeModel.objects.filter(focus__priority__in=priority_ids)`). I think you have to do it this way for `all`.

Answer (score 0):

You can query dynamically with Q() as below...

```
from django.db.models import Q 
from priority_app.models import Priority  # get your model identified


#(whatever API place you had this):

    priority_id = request.GET.get("priority")   #getlist is isn't a proper list
    field_id = request.query_params.get('collection')
    if priority_id:
        priority_id_list = list(map(str.strip, priority_id.split(",")))


        dynamic_query_filters = Priority.objects.none()
        for a_item in priority_id_list:
            if collection == "any":
                dynamic_query_filters |= (Q(id=a_item))    # OR query
            else:
                dynamic_query_filters &= (Q(id=a_item))   # AND query
    
        queryset = Priority.objects.filter(dynamic_query_filters)   
        # you will notice, it executes in order of "query", maybe take them in different variables and chain them accordingly.
```

Comment: This is a literal solution to how the question asked was attempting to resolve.